# Which script is responsible for mounting an HGFS share on an Ubuntu 16.04 guest running on a Windows host in VMWare Workstation 12?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

I'm trying to change the permissions of the mount so that the owner of all files/folders in the shared folder residing on the Windows host doesn't default to root. I've found this http://www.zendbox.de/2015/10/10/how-to-change-the-owner-on-a-shared-hgfs-folder/ but I figure there has to be a better way--like modifying the script that mounts it in the first place. There's nothing in my fstab so I'm sort of confused.